# Flutter - Stop audio playback from recorded video in the background

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-dependencies

Essentially the app is like snapchat. I take pics and reset back to camera mode, the issue comes when I record video and reset, it goes back to camera mode but the audio form the video keeps playing in the background. The functions are somwhat exactly like the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) doc, with a few addition to reset the camera.

I added this:

```
_reset() {
  if (mounted)
   setState(() {
    if (this._didCapture) {
      this._didCapture = false;
      this._isRecording = false;
      this._isPosting = false;
      this._file = File('');
      this._fileType = null;
      this._captions.clear();
      this._textEditingControllers.clear();
      this._videoController = null;
      this._videoPlayerListener = null;
    }
  });
}
```

It works just fine but the audio in the background is still on. Also wondering if the video/picture is saved on the phone, which I don't want to...

Comment: have you tried to remove the controller in dispose function in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

i had been looking for a similar answer, but i didn´t find it. You could try to stop it adding this to your function:

this._controller.setVolume(0.0);

that´s what i did in my app